# Connection between a function and its usage in geometry

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know nothing about geometry, but I found a function which seems to have something to do with geometry.

This function is, $$f(x,y,z) = \dfrac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$$

where $x,y,z$ is the coordinates of $R^3$ and $(x,y,z)$ is a vector of these variables.

I recall from a PDE class many years ago that this has something to do with surface area. But I cannot immediately see the connection. Also it looks like the normalization of a vector, but I have no idea what the $1$ is doing in there.

Does anyone who deal with geometry see the connection between this function with some concepts such as path length, minimal surface, etc.?

Comment: It is a diffeomorphism from $\Bbb R^3$ onto the open unit ball.